# xhtml vs html5 native web component behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, native-web-component

I have exactly the same html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<script>
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello world</p>`;
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which works as I would have expected in both FF and Chrome if the file is served as `Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8`. If it is served as `Content-Type application/xhtml+xml` then they are both empty. I appear to get the same behaviour with or without the `shadowDom`.

If I have

```
this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `hello world`;
```

Then I do get `hello world`. I get exactly the same behaviour on both FF and Chrome, so it looks like it's working as expected - where is this documented?

Is it because the browsers DOMs APIs are stopping being html5 DOMs and becoming XML DOMs, meaning that it is not longer possible to assign to `innerHTML`, and requires using tools like `DOMParser`, et al.?

Comment: I think this a good question for the developers at https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with the way the XML parser works. The `<p>...</p>` tags are parsed as an *element* by the XML parser and not as text as the HTML parser would do, so the `p` element and its contents are never part of the string input to .innerHTML.

If you extract the JavaScript to an external file, and reference that instead, then it works fine because the JavaScript is then not being handed to the HTML/XML parser.

Alternatively, you can escape the `<` characters. So

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<script>
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `&lt;p>hello world&lt;/p>`;
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The opposite compatibility applies though. It will work as desired in the `application/xhtml+xml` content type, but will interpret the tags as text in the `text/html` content type.

If you really need bi-glot behaviour and everything in the HTML file, you can use the "to end-of-line-commented CDATA hack". i.e.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello world</p>`;
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, bi-glot HTML really isn't a thing any more. Just go with the content type you prefer.

Comment: Actually I was using this to try and debug another issue, and didn't ever consider that it would be taken as markup. So I ended up having a bug in my debug code... Browser JS literally takes me 5x longer to write than non-JS code for any other environment!